# Raspberry pi controlling sound files with buttons on Web page

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to make a Web page that will play/pause multiple sounds stored on the raspberry pi using different buttons on the page. Each button will be linked to a specific sound but I want to be able to view the page on my phone to play the sounds through the raspberry pi. So far I haven't found any software that can do this. Can anyone help me please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create an html file and then use javascript to create buttons which play sounds when they get clicked (click listener):

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onplay.asp

And then you can put your html and audio files in your Apache server folder (which I think is `/var/www`)

Comment: So if I do the above I can click the buttons on my phone and hear them through the raspberry pi audio jack?

Comment: Yep, if you are on a local network.

If you want to connect without using your local network, you must open some ports to your router.